# Ubuntu booting slowly

Tags: 14.04, boot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit on a laptop with an Intel core i5-5200U processor and 4GB RAM. On booting, the GRUB menu loads very quickly, but after selecting Ubuntu the screen alternates between purple and black for about 20 seconds, after which the Ubuntu logo appears for 5 seconds. Then a black screen with an error message saying that "The master interrupt lied!" appears or a couple of seconds.Then the login screen appears. After logging in, my wallpaper is displayed, but my desktop icons and dock (I am running Docky) do not appear. After about 15 seconds, everything loads fine. On a side note, Chrome loads pretty slowly on starting it the first time, after which it loads fast. On running dmesg I found an error:

```
       57.747822] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* The master control            interrupt lied (SDE)!
[   57.747974] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* The master control interrupt lied (SDE)!
```

Is there any way to speed up boot up time? Also, is there any way to solve the error?

Additional information:

1. Some time ago, when I shut down, the screen used  to display a black screen for a couple of seconds which had the same error displayed
2. I am using a proprietary NVIDIA driver.

Comment: Usually boot speed issues come from having a lot of software installed (in my experience) or having an installation for an extended period of time (especially if you've upgraded between versions). How long have you been running this installation and did you install a lot of software?

The master interrupt issue *might* be a separate issue.

Comment: I've been running this for about a month.  I've installed about 20 programs.

Comment: The Master Interrupt issue looks like it has something to do with the graphics driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695269/ubuntu-15-10-installation-error-the-master-control-interrupt-lied-sde

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve it?